# How to join Medium without having Google or Facebook account?

Tags: medium

I do not have Google, Facebook or Twitter account. I do not use social media. But I want join Medium. I have a non-Google email id. How can I join Medium? I am not seeing any option to create account using email id. Is there any way to join Medium directly using email id, without having any social media?
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a bit deceptive the way they've laid it out on the page.

Go to the "Sign In" link under the two options.  Click "Sign in with Email," and if you enter your email address, they will send you an email with a link.

You don't have to have had an account already to do so.

Answer (score 2):

> ## Sign in or sign up by email
>
> Creating your Medium account or signing in with an email address is quick and easy.
>
> 1. On the [Medium homepage](https://medium.com/), click **Sign in** in the top-right corner.
> 2. Choose **Sign in with email**.
> 3. Enter your email address and click **Continue**.
> 4. Go to your inbox and open the verification email.
> 5. Click **Sign in to Medium** in the email to be redirected to Medium and signed in to your account.

[Source](https://help.medium.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004915268).

Answer (score 1):

As answered by [jonsca](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/121796/87130) and [Alex](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/123519/87130) you can just try to sign in and it pretends to create an account by sending you a confirmation email. However, this only leads to a payment page for a paid account.

If you sign up with Google or Facebook, you'll get a free account, but of course your data is shared with Medium.

So it seems the only way to get an anonymous account is to wait until the Medium app on iOS has to offer (on Apple's request) a "Sign up with Apple" choice where you can opt to have an anonymous mail address. Probably in April 2020.

Answer (score 0):

**Create throw-away Gmail and Facebook accounts** for use with any system requiring them.

Because, even if you make it to the Medium "sign in with email" page, unless you are using an address for a large corporate domain, it will reject it with:

**"Sorry, we didn't recognize that email."**

You could create a throw away email account, but as more and more apps/systems are gobbled up by these behemoths, the more likely it will be that you run into this. E.g. Oculus, Instagram, YouTube. You may as well be prepared.

*Be careful not to link your throw-away with your real account* if you have one, or there isn't a point.

This can be tricky with Facebook. They figure out you already have an account and try to be "helpful" and link them if you don't strenuously resist. If you have been silly enough to install their app on your phone, it is can be quite difficult to do this, in my experience (helping friends, I wouldn't install an app for either company).

If you are in the "they know everything any way" camp, you're wrong. But, you probably aren't looking for this answer either.